# How to solve this limit of piecewise function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Basically, I am trying to solve this problem here, but I am stuck as to what to do first. My only idea is to substitute the x-values, but I do not know what to do after. What happens when they are true and false and how can I solve a? Can someone please help me. Thanks. [Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Jiz.png)

Comment: Have you tried graphing the function?

Comment: No, will graphing it help?

Comment: Yes. Left and right hand limits are named this way because of the behavior of the graph at points of discontinuity. See if you can figure out why.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this algebraically?

Comment: You can solve it algebraically but I recommend graphing it first then working on the algebraic proof. Being able to easily translate between the graphical representation and the symbolic representation can make many problems in analysis transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be saying that you do not know what a "limit" is.
$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= \lim_{x\to a+} f(x)$
and
$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= \lim_{x\to a-} f(x)$
where "$x\to a+$ means "using only numbers above a"
and "$x\to a-$ means "using only numbers below a".

If those two "one-sided" limits are not the same then the limit does not exist.

Here, for x<-1, f(x)= 1.  What is the limit of that as x goes to -1?  For x> -1 (but close to -1) f(x)= -x.  What is the limit of that as x goes to -1?  Are those the same?

For x< 0, but close to 0, f(x)= -x.  What is the limit of that as x goes to 0?  For x> 0, but close to 0, f(x)= -x.  What is the limit of that as x goes to 0?  Are those the same?

For x< 1, but close to 1, f(x)= -x.  What is the limit of that as x goes to 1?  For x> 1, but close to 1, f(x)= 1.  What is the limit of that as x goes to 1?  Are those the same?